# Program for two-way synchronization of big files (VM disk images)

Tags: software-rec, synchronization, disk-image

I heavily use virtual machines in my work and I need an efficient way of synchronizing them between my PCs.

I know of [bigsync](https://github.com/egorFiNE/bigsync/), but this program works well only for one-way synchronizing (like rsync).

Unison is also insufficient, because it always copies target files before updating them, which is unacceptable for >16GB disk images.

I need a tool or a script for two-way synchronization in place, something that will work like `bigsync` except it will first test which file is more recent by inspecting the modification date and whether the contents changed after last use (btrfs filesystem has nice features to test that), and - unlike `bigsync` will work efficiently both ways (AFAIK `bigsync` works efficiently only one way: from source to destination. For the other way, one needs to call it from the remote end).

Comment: why dont you use NFS and have it on a fileserver? you can store the file in a centralized location and mount it on more than one host. then you don't have to synchronize anything.

Comment: @son_of_fire I don't always work online. And even if I did, the wifi is unreliable, so NFS would hardly a medium for backing storage for virtual machine.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski why not use a versionning software like git or mercurial that also work offline ? and you can choose exactly what you want to keep and even having a history of file

Comment: Are you asking how to keep the VM images in sync or the contents of something inside the VM. These are 2 very different problems.

Comment: @Kiwy Are you sure, that git work on parts of the file? Maybe things changed, but few years ago, the smallest object the git could hangle was a whole file. Git also stores history, which I don't need (VirtualBox already has snapshots). If I used git, I would fill 200GB of storage each month, if I ever waited that long to have that amount of data copied.

Comment: @slm Just as in title: I need to manage the files as a whole. The fact that they happen to be images of virtual machines is given only as a rationale.

Comment: You can't use git here, that's not an option!

Comment: if you want to update the difference between two binary file you will need to have both files at the same time, virtual box does that with snapshot why not using git to save snapshots ? @slm it depends he could, just need to limitate the number of history keep

Comment: No git doesn't handle binary data well, it's gears towards textual data. http://robinwinslow.co.uk/2013/06/11/dont-ever-commit-binary-files-to-git/

Comment: Virtualbox uses something similar to what Docker and LXC use to create a overlay file that delta data can be tracked in, git does not work like this, git would require full checkins of each image as a whole to track the "delta".

Comment: Would a solution that involves live monitoring of the VMs be ok? Would involving guest software be ok? Is this a generic requirement, or might you switch to a VM system with a dedicated built-in feature (I think VMware does but I am not at all familiar with it)?

Comment: @Gilles It may, but I guess viable, robust and simple solution can be found using methods, that don't take into account the nature of the data.

Comment: @slm how does Git not handle binary data well? The (delta) compression is unrelated to the file contents. Of course some features, like a line-based diff or `git blame` doesn't work well if your file has no notion of lines -- but other than that, I successfully used Git to efficiently store and sync many GB of binary data. In particular, Git's compression also kicks in if you just check in two independent VMs, and the repository will only grow very little if you add further VMs.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe - read the link I cite. It explains it.

Answer (score 3):

Because of @Kiwy's persistence that you could use Git to do this in the comments, it reminded me of a tool that I'd seen a while ago called [`git-annex`](http://git-annex.branchable.com/). In refreshing myself on what `git-annex` can do I remembered coming across this post in the `git-annex` forums.

> #### Synchronize large files (VM images)
>
> Hi,
>
> I'm thinking to use git-annex to synchronize my virtual machine
>   directory (Virtualbox) between 3 pc. It's quite big: more than 200GB
>   and some of the images are 40Gb in size.
>
> The synchronization will be over a lan (obviously). It is already in
>   place with 2pc and unison but the configuration of the 3rd pc is
>   cumbersome. Does anybody have experiences with git-annex and such
>   amount of data?
>
> Thanks in advance
>
> Gabriele

To which the author of `git-annex` replied:

> This volume of data should be no problem for git-annex.
>
> The only catch would be if you're running those VM images and want to
>   sync them as they're changed. With git-annex, you'd need to git annex
>   unlock a file to allow it to be modified, and then git annex add it
>   back and commit changes made to it.

#### So it's just Git?

But be clear on this point. Git-annex is not pure Git. It uses the interface that `git` provides but uses a variety of different backends for doing the actual shuttling of data back and forth. Read the "[How it works](http://git-annex.branchable.com/how_it_works/)" page for more on this.

> The contents of 'annexed' files are not stored in git, only the names of the files and some other metadata remain there.

For more on how it handles the "transferring of data" take a look at this section of the site titled: "[transferring data](http://git-annex.branchable.com/transferring_data/).

#### Special remotes

The genius in `git-annex`'s approach is in the "special remotes". This allows the backends to be essentially plugged in and are therefore modular in nature. You can see a full list of the various "[special remotes](http://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/)" here.

#### References

- [Managing large binary files with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git)

Comment: I'm glad it remind you this :D also I was pretty sure the virutalBox was saving binary difference between the original disk and the snapshot in separate file (buit that's maybe from a while ago).

Comment: @Kiwy - VB does save the differences in files, Docker and LXC too. See this diagram for what I was talking about wrt Docker: https://www.docker.io/static/img/about/modifying_updating.jpg

Comment: The video highlights some impressive feats being accomplished with git-annex too: http://campaign.joeyh.name/

Comment: As an alternative to `git-annex` there's another tool called `bup` https://github.com/bup/bup, which can be used to do similar things, it too hinges off of Git's API, "...Capable of doing *fast* incremental backups of virtual machine images...."

Comment: Yes. `bup` seems a way to go - it is designed specifically for my purpose.

Comment: bup has several limitations so far, but its development is quite active. The most limiting is lack of garbage collection and removal of old backups. Which would mean, that eventually the database will be HUGE.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski - yes when dealing with these large files that's the other major issue.

Comment: `bup` has apparently resolved the issue with garbage collection of old (deleted) backups (https://github.com/bup/bup/commit/42b51652e6f470b3da17ec7b541f610a1b0ad7a6)

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski - good to know.